# When importing multilevel list from xhtml to docx a few concrete lists are generated per one numbered list

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I have to import multilevel numbered list from xhtml to docx.
When importing the list to docx one abstract list in NumberingDefinitionsPart is created. 
The abstract list determines style of the numbered list and it should have been the same for all the list elements.
But for some elements of the list different concrete lists
with different NumId are generated in NumberingDefinitionsPart. 
The concrete lists override style of numbered list, determined in abstract list. But there is no need to change style across numbered list as it is the same.
Below is xhtml of original numbered list:

```
<ol>
    <li>level 1
    <ol>
        <li>level 1.1</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>level 2
    <ol>
        <li>level 2.1</li>
        <li>level 2.2</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

After converting to docx it is converted to such a content:

```
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="3"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>level 1</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="3"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>level 1.1</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="3"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>level 2</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="4"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>level 2.1</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
            <w:numId w:val="4"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>level 2.2</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

So for list elements up till "level 4" its w:numId is 3, but starting from element  "level 4.1" its w:numId is 4. That is not clear as numbering is the same and style for numbering should not have changed.
As a result when exporting the numbered list back to xhtml the list element numbering is broken and restarts from 0 on changing concrete list.

Docx4j version is 6.1.2, xHTMLImporter is called in the next way:

```
String strRich;//string with xhtml
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<html>").append("<head>").append("<style type='text/css'>")
.append("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{ font-size:12pt;}")
.append("body { font-size:12pt;}")
.append("</style>").append("</head>")
.append("<body>")
.append(strRich)
.append("</body>")
.append("</html>");
XHTMLImporterImpl xHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(inwordMLPackage);
xHTMLImporter.setRunFormatting(FormattingOption.IGNORE_CLASS);
xHTMLImporter.setTableFormatting(FormattingOption.IGNORE_CLASS);
xHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
List<Object> addhtml = xHTMLImporter.convert(sb.toString(), null);
```

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/ListHelper.java#L498

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Jason! It is not quite clear the purpose of restarting numbering and  recreating ConcreteList for numberedList at lines 582-589 of ListHelper. But in our case this functionality is not demanded. Is it possible to turn off restarting numbering by some new Docx4J parameter? In this case it is enough to initialize isFirstItem to false at line 175 of ListHelper.

Comment: I have the same problem now. Have you found a solution?